# httpOnly cookie between rest api(Spring Boot) and VueJS

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, cookies

I am implementing Spring Boot API and VueJS. And actually everything works when i am just storing the JWT to localstorage.

Now many articles on the internet, says "don't store jwt in the localstorage, store it as httpOnly cookie to avoid XSS attacks"

Now i am just trying to do that, but after creating the httpOnly cookie, the next request doesn't contain the cookie.

Spring Boot running on localhost:8080 and VueJs running on localhost:8081

SecurityConfiguration:

```java
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:8081", "http://localhost:8082"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(Duration.ofMinutes(10));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.cors().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                ...
    }
}
```

In the login endpoint:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class LoginController {
    ...

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> doLogin(@RequestBody @Valid MyRequest loginRequest, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String jwt = loginService.doLogin(loginRequest);
        ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from("my-http-only-cookie", jwt)
                .path("/")
                .httpOnly(true)
                .build();

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookie.toString())
                .body(jwt);
    }
}
```

Now if i send the login request from the vuejs(8081) i can see the set-cookies response:

```
Set-Cookie: my-http-only-cookie=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.e...; Path=/; HttpOnly;
```

But the following ajax requests don't include the cookie called my-http-only-cookie, i can verify this in my OncePerRequestFilter:

```java
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        for (Cookie eachCookie : request.getCookies()) {
            logger.info("Cookie name: {} and value: {}", eachCookie.getName(), eachCookie.getValue());
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    ...
}
```

And also in the VueJs application i am sending ajax request like this:

```js
testRequest(jwt) {
    return axios.post("/...", ... , {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + jwt,
      },
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }
```

As far as i know cookies are not shared between different domains such as localhost:8080 & localhost:8081. Then how can i implement most secure httpOnly jwt cookie?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create cookie with "localhost" without port to share it between localhost:8080 and localhost:8081, example:

```
public static void createWithHttpOnly(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, String token) {
  javax.servlet.http.Cookie.Cookie cookie = new Cookie("my-http-only-cookie", token);
  cookie.setSecure(true);
  cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
  cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
  cookie.setDomain("localhost");
  cookie.setPath("/");
  httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
}
```